# Access export to XML error

Tags: xml, ms-access, export

I have a problem when exporting an Access table to XML.

Basically what I am doing is first running a select query which takes the columns I want from 2 tables and puts them into one, then I can just right click this table and Export as XML.

The select looks like:

```
SELECT 
   tblProducts.ProductID, 
   tblProducts.Description, 
   tblStock.Stock, 
   tblStock.Min, 
   tblStock.Max,
   StoreID
 INTO
   tblTempStockExport
FROM
   tblProducts 
INNER JOIN
   tblStock
ON
   tblProducts.STK = tblStock.ID
WHERE
   tblStock.Stock > 0
OR
   tblStock.Min > 0
OR
   tblStock.Max > 0;
```

The StoreID param is not in a table and will prompt the user to enter a value when the query runs, this part works ok and when I view my new table the data is all correct, however when I do the XML import the value that I typed in seems to be encoded incorrectly and displays as:

```
<StoreID>QQBsAGEAbgA=</StoreID>
```

Is there anything I'm missing here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the data you got back is base64 encoded. Access does this for binary types, but I have no idea why it comes back like that.
Have a look in the corresponding XSD file to see if it really is base64 encoded and what XML datatype Access thinks it should be.

You can always try to decode the data using a base64 VBA routine (such as [this VB6/VBA code - haven't looked at it, though](http://www.nonhostile.com/howto-encode-decode-base64-vb6.asp).

What datatype is it? A long integer autonumber? Or something else? 
Decoding the sample using [an online base64 decoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/Base64Decode/) gives some 2 byte character set with what seems like Alan in it.

Also, you're not saying what version of Access you're using and if you have applied the latest servicepack - that may help sometimes.